# Open a query saved in a table in SysQueryForm AX2009

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

How is it possible to open a query that is saved in a table as a container in in SysQueryForm, edit the query and then save it again in the table?

I know already how to save it to the table and read it from the table, but I cannot find out how it is possible to open the query in SysQueryForm and let the user edit it and then save it.

OR

What is a good way of storing or having a query that a user can adjust and that can also be ran in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You show the edit form via the `prompt()` method of class `SysQueryRun`. I don't show how to load and store it in a table as you mentioned that you already know how to do this.

```
SysQueryRun queryRun;
;

queryRun = loadQueryFromTable();
if (queryRun.prompt()) // show dialog
{
    info("Closed via 'OK'");
    saveQueryInTable(queryRun);
}
else
{
    info("Closed via 'Cancel'");
}
```

Comment: Saving to a table involves container fields, example: http://dynamicsax-dev.blogspot.dk/2008/10/displaying-and-saving-query.html